# First order logic representation of this statement?

Tags: first-order-logic

For the expression

> The flight from boston arrived.

I need to give an event oriented First Order Logic representation.

If it was `the flight arrived`, I would have said

> Arrived(e) ^ arrived_thing(e,flight)

How do I incorporate the propositional phrase`from boston` in it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep Arrived and arrived_thing

> Arrived(e) ^ Arrived_thing(e,flight) ^ Before(boston, flight)

Hope this helps.